# Can an eigenvalue have more than one cycle of generalized eigenvectors associated with it?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, invariant-subspace

*There is a theorem in Freidberg that goes like this. This is exposition leading to Jordan Form discussion.*

---

Theorem 7.6. Let T be a linear operator on a vector space $\mathrm{V},$ and let
$\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of T. Suppose that $\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2}, \ldots, \gamma_{q}$ are cycles of generalized eigenvectors of T corresponding to $\lambda$ such that the initial vectors of the $\gamma_{i}$ 's are distinct and form a linearly independent set. Then the $\gamma_{i}$ 's are disjoint, and their union $\gamma=\bigcup_{i=1}^{q} \gamma_{i}$ is linearly independent.

---

**Is it true then that the only way a particular eigenvalue $\lambda_{particular}$ can have multiple disjoint cycles $\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2}, .., \gamma_{i} $ associated with it if it had at least that many ($i$) lin.indep (non-generalized) eigenvectors associated with it to begin with?**

In other words, if i got a defective 3x3 matrix $A$ with only one eigenvalue $\lambda_{particular} = 1$ then it is a given that it has a cycle of three lin. indep. generalized eigenvectors but *also* it is a given that it cannot have multiple cycles associated with it and this holds for arbitrary dimensions of $A$.

I would appreciate if somebody could confirm this or provide a counter example. Thank you tons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  In particular, there are exactly as many generalized eigenvector cycles as there are linearly independent eigenvectors. To see this, the last element in any chain is an eigenvector; conversely, for any eigenvector we can build a cycle that has length at least $1$.

Comment: Huh. To your statement  "as many generalized eigenvector cycles as there are eigenvalues"... this is what i thought right before i read this proof! 
But it seems to hint that there may be multiple cycles associated with a single eigenvalue, no? As in, maybe the eigenspace for some $\lambda$ is strictly smaller than its generalized eigenspace(let's say $dim(E_{\lambda}) = 2$ and $dim(K_{\lambda}) = 5$ , so wouldn't that be where those two eigenvectors have to yield a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle? Sorry if i'm getting this backwards

Comment: @rtviii Sorry I said that incorrectly at first; see my latest edit

Comment: That makes perfect sense now thank you so much!